# How to Handle Confirm With Selenium +Phantomjs

Tags: c#, phantomjs

```
PhantomJSDriverService driverservice = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverservice .LoadImages = false;
driverservice .HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverservice .AddArgument(@"page.onAlert = function(msg) {};");
driverservice .AddArgument(@"page.onConfirm = function(msg){return true;};");

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverservice);
```

Above method cannot be processed Confirm.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JavascriptExecutor` worked for me. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invokes alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note:- do not use it after clicking on the event which invokes alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked